# Winform ComboBox binding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

This is something that just started happening. I have a ComboBox that is misbehaving.
When the Form opens, the values shown are not what the actual Bound fields have.
If you look at the screen print below, the Printer shows `TITAN Print 2`. A hint its wrong is the DataGridView shows the correct value `TITAN Print 1`.

The DataSet has `TP1` which should display `TITAN Print 1`.  It only happens on startup. I have came up with a patch in the Shown event to force the field to the correct value but I shouldn't have to do this. I don't know what I did wrong but I would like to figure it out.

```
If Me.Shift_PrinterBindingSource.Current("SP_Printer_Id") IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim CurrPrt As String = Me.Shift_PrinterBindingSource.Current("SP_Printer_Id")
    cmbPrinter.SelectedValue = CurrPrt
End If
```

Here is the generated code for the control.

```
'cmbPrinter
'
Me.cmbPrinter.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.Shift_PrinterBindingSource, "SP_Printer_Id", True))
Me.cmbPrinter.DataSource = Me.PrintersBindingSource
Me.cmbPrinter.DisplayMember = "PrinterName"
Me.cmbPrinter.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
Me.cmbPrinter.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
Me.cmbPrinter.FormattingEnabled = True
Me.cmbPrinter.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(75, 56)
Me.cmbPrinter.Name = "cmbPrinter"
Me.cmbPrinter.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(145, 21)
Me.cmbPrinter.TabIndex = 7
Me.cmbPrinter.ValueMember = "PrinterID"
```

[image: The table Values]

[image: The screen as displayed]

[image: Control Binding]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `DataBindings` you added? The Control is already bound to a BindingSource, when you set the DataSource.

Comment: When binding, set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` first, then the `DataSource`. Bind the `SelectedValue` last. How do you expect a binding to `SelectedValue` to work if there's no `DataSource`?

Comment: Thank you, That rings a bell form my classes now that you said it